# Migrate from Windows Server 2008 Active Directory to Samba4

Tags: ldap, migration, samba4

I'd like to migrate from Windows Server 2008 Active Directory to Samba4 AD as our primary domain server.

An hour of Googling has not landed me any clear recipes for doing a migration and it is unclear to me what the procedure is.

Can anyone provide me with a summary of the steps involved or a pointer to a recipe for this?

Answer (score 0):

According to [the Samba 4 page](https://wiki.samba.org/index.php/Join_an_additional_Samba_DC_to_an_existing_Active_Directory) it's the same as adding a DC to a Samba domain. Just add the Samba 4 DC's and eventually demote the Windows DCs.

Comment: "Join" is not a word I used in my searches as I was thinking more along the lines or replacing or migrating. Thank you for the pointer.